# Combinatorics - Sequence from a multiset with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Consider the following multiset:
$$
\begin{align*}
\{a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_k,\underbrace{x,x,\cdots,x}_{\text{m times}},\underbrace{y,y\cdots y}_{\text{n times}}\}
\end{align*}
$$
How many sequences can be made using all symbols of the multiset with the restriction that every y is separated by at least one x at the left and at the right?

---

**My Answer:**

First make a sequence with all the y's: $\frac{n!}{n!} = 1$.

After that, distribute the x's in the spaces created by y's considering the restriction:
$$
(\underbrace{\_}_{\text{slot 1}} y \underbrace{\_}_{\text{slot 2}} \cdots \underbrace{\_}_{\text{slot n}} y \underbrace{\_}_{\text{slot n+1}}) \rightarrow s_1+s_2+\cdots + s_{n+1} = m \text{ such that } s_i \geq 1
$$
To solve the number of solutions of that equation, use stars and bars method:
$$
\begin{align*}
s_1+s_2+\cdots +s_{n+1} &= m \text{ such that } s_i \geq 1\\
s_1'+s_2'+\cdots +s'_{n+1} &= m -(n+1) = m-n-1\text{ such that } s'_i \geq 0
\end{align*}
$$
The number of solutions is:
$$
{m-n-1+n \choose n} = {m-1 \choose n}
$$
Now we have a sequence with $n+m$ elements considering the restriction. Let's distribute the $a_i$'s in the sequence with no restriction:
$$
s_1+s_2+\cdots +s_{n+m+1} = k \text{ such that } s_i\geq 0
$$
The number of solutions is:
$$
{n+m+k\choose n+m}
$$
Then, for each of those distributions of $a_i$'s, organize them in all possible ways: $k!$. Hence my final answer is:
$$
1{m-1 \choose n}{n+m+k\choose n+m} k!
$$

---

**Sanity Check:** As a good practice, I'm always trying to do some sanity checks in my answers, since combinatorics can be very subtle sometimes...

Considering the multiset with $k = 1$, $n=1$ and $m=2$ we would have the following sequences:
$$
(a_1xyx)\\
(xa_1yx)\\
(xya_1x)\\
(xyxa_1)
$$
Validating my answer:
$$
1{2-1 \choose 1}{1+2+1\choose 1+2} 1! = 1\cdot 1 \cdot {4 \choose 3} \cdot 1 = 4
$$

---

Is everything correct? Any help and critics are highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What worries me is that the wording every $y$ must be separated by an $x$ on both the left and the right suggests that the sequence $a_1xxy$ should be permissible since there are not two $y$s to separate.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig But considering that sequences as you've mentioned are not allowed, do you think that my reasoning is correct?

Comment: If sequences with a $y$ on the end are not permitted, then your solution is correct.